# Can i access a windows share directly from linux server and Copy files

Tags: php, linux, windows, ubuntu, samba

I have a windows share created using samba .

It is located in my ubunutu server `/mnt/user_new` I want to copy files from `/var/www/myproject/files/`  to `/mnt/user_new/files` . This is for backup my files . and delete the original files .

I am using PHP . form PHP i tried

```
$file = '/var/www/myproject/files/0000000.pdf';
$newfile = '/mnt/user_new/0000000.pdf';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

But i get a permission denied error .

```
Severity: Warning

Message: copy(/mnt/user_new/0000000.pdf) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Is there any way to copy files from my Linux server to windows share . I have a username and password for access window share , but i don't know how to use it here . is there any way i can pass username and password .

To be honest this is my first time working with Samba , and the windows share is created by Network administrator . I have spent nearly 8 hours for this simple copy . but could not do .

Please help me . thanks in advance .

Comment: I think you should set the permissions at mount time, so that the web server's user or group (typically www-data) has right to write to the share. Look at mount.cifs documentation: you can use gid=www-data parameter

Comment: @tzunghaor i checked my windows share files permission , it is 755 .

Comment: 755 allows write only for the mounting user, and that is probably not the web server's user. I suggest to pass the "uid=www-data" parameter when you mount the share. If that works, you can try "gid=www-data,file_mode=775,dir_mode=775" instead of it, so the owner permission allows you to write, and the group permission allows the web server to write.